# MYSQL Update Connection Error with ->

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am doing an update statement into my database. My connection has been done properly. However there is an issue. After `$conn->` the remaining of my codes are being displayed out just like echo instead of the update statement updating the database. I have been trying to debug it but nothing seems to work. Unsure of the error. Do help to identify the error.

```
   <?php//check on the updating
   if (isset($_POST['set'])){
       $query = 'UPDATE default SET sql_statement ="'.$_POST['sql'].'", x_axis = "'.$_POST['x'].'", y_axis = "'.$_POST['y'].'" WHERE id = "'.$id.'" ';
       $result = $conn->query($query);
       if($result){
           header('Location:previewgraphs.php?id='.$id);
           die();
       }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some where your php tags have problem. So use `"` to wrap and also when you are using `array` index in concatenation, wrap them with `{}`

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['set'])){
   $query = "UPDATE default SET sql_statement ='{$_POST['sql']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
   $result = $conn->query($query);
   header('Location:previewgraphs.php?id='.$id);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. What if I want to do a page refresh after updating instead of redirecting to the page. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: you are on same page?? i mean your php code is in same page with html??

Comment: Yes. Its a pop up box on the same page. So once updated, I need to refresh the page so the contents are updated. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I only want to refresh after doing an update. So the page will just auto refresh when I click the update button

Comment: <?php $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
$result = $conn->query($query);header("Refresh: 0; url=previewgraphs.php?id=".$id);
   }
?> Not refreshing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php//check on the updating
       if (isset($_POST['set'])){
       $query = 'UPDATE default SET sql_statement ="'.$_POST['sql'].'", x_axis = "'.$_POST['x'].'", y_axis = "'.$_POST['y'].'" WHERE id = "'.$id.'" ';
       $result = $conn->query($query);
       if($result){
       header('Location:previewgraphs.php?id='.$id);
       die();
       }
     }
       ?>
```

Comment: Still dosent work out. All the remaining after the -> is still being shown      query($query);
       if($result){
       header('Location:previewgraphs.php?id='.$id);
       die();
       }
     }
       ?>

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju, we always need to write die() after header for proper redirection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php//check on the updating
               if (isset($_POST['set'])){
               $query = "UPDATE default SET sql_statement ='".$_POST['sql']."', x_axis = '".$_POST['x']."', y_axis = '".$_POST['y']."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
               $result = $conn->query($query);
               if($result){
               header('Location:previewgraphs.php?id='.$id);
               die();
               }
             }
             ?>
```